# How to Calculate a Remaining value in a Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I currently have a databases exam and one of the questions is asking me to find out how many tickets are remaining at a event.

There are `5` events and a `NumOfAdultsTickets` field and a `NumOfChildTickets` field so I would need to add both them values together and then take away that value from `80` which is the total amount of tickets for that event location.

In a query I've tried grouping the number of adults and the number of childs and then having a calculation field that adds the two values and then subtracts that value from `80` but that gives me a value of something like `-1000`.

Help would be greatly appreciated please.

Comment: You have to `GROUP BY` event and `SUM` the number of tickets.

Comment: Edit question to show the attempted query SQL.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in the access query designer with a totals query that includes a calculated variable.  I fortified the database design with a ticket type table and included seats as a variable under event venue.  For the mock data the first event had tickets for 2 adults and 1 child.  the second event had 4 adults and 2 children.  the query looks like:
[image]

The query gives the correct result for the example data:

[image]

For completeness here is the resulting SQL:

```
SELECT Tickets.EventVenueID, EventVenues.EventSeats, Count(Tickets.TicketID) AS CountOfTicketID, [EventVenues].[EventSeats]-Count([Tickets].[TicketID]) AS [Seats Remaining]
FROM TicketTypes INNER JOIN (EventVenues INNER JOIN Tickets ON EventVenues.EventVenueID = Tickets.EventVenueID) ON TicketTypes.TicketTypeID = Tickets.TicketTypeID
GROUP BY Tickets.EventVenueID, EventVenues.EventSeats;
```